# How to filter a two columns with specific values in pandas

Tags: pandas

I want to filter two columns Administration  and State column and print the values where state is California.

```
df.head()

   R&D Spend  Administration  Marketing Spend       State     Profit
0  165349.20       136897.80        471784.10    New York  192261.83
1  162597.70       151377.59        443898.53  California  191792.06
2  153441.51       101145.55        407934.54     Florida  191050.39
```

I tried to filter the values but i get only the boolean values.How to print the values?

```
df.loc[:,['Administration','State']].isin(['California'])

    Administration  State
0   False   False
1   False   True
2   False   False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `any` on `axis=1` then boolean indexing:

```
df[df.loc[:,['Administration','State']].isin(['California']).any(1)]
```

Or for only 2 columns `['Administration','State']`:

```
df.loc[df['State'].isin(['California']),['Administration','State']] #or.eq() for 1 value
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only have one column , you can do `eq`

```
df[df[['Administration','State']].eq('California').any(1)]
```